# Problem with alltt package when defining new command

Tags: pdftex

I have following problem. In the code below the second parameter of new command 'chunk' is supposed to output text 'as-is' using alltt package (I need alltt because I will output some other new commands). What instead happens is that all text is displayed in one line (my guess is => parameter causes this).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[a4paper, inner=1.5cm, outer=3cm, top=2cm, bottom=3cm, bindingoffset=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{alltt}

\newcommand{\chunk}[2]{ 
    \label{#1}
    $\langle\textit{#1}\ \rangle\equiv$
    \begin{alltt}
        #2
    \end{alltt}
}

\begin{document}

\chunk{Example}{
    some ex ample
    \{
        som e t e xt
            te xt
    \}
}

\end{document}
```

Now, the quick fix I came up with would remove usage of alltt from the chunk command and instead use alltt in the document directly like this

```
\chunk{Example}
\begin{alltt}
    some ex ample
    \{
        som e t e xt
            te xt
    \}
\end{alltt}
```

but this approach is ugly and leads to code repetition so I would like to avoid it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The LaTeX style for a command taking large chunks of text, especially if (as here) you need to change the scanning conventions is to use an environment not a command. If you did

```
\newenvironment{chunk}[1]
{%
    \label{#1}%
    $\langle\textit{#1}\ \rangle\equiv$%
    \begin{alltt}}
{\end{alltt}}
```

then line endings in the environment would be preserved. Also note that you need `%` at the end of lines in macro definitions or you will get spurious spaces in the output.

```
\begin{chunk}{Example}
    some ex ample
    \{
        som e t e xt
            te xt
    \}
\end{chunk}
```

Comment: Thank you, just what I needed (will upvote when I earn 15 rep). Looks like I have some reading about environments to do.