# passing text to alltt embeded in command (extra newline needed)

Tags: spacing, environments, verbatim

I wanted to close `alltt` inside a command (to add some ornaments around the text), but the spaces that were used for putting the monospaced text into columns was not preserved.

I found the solution here:
[Problem with alltt package when defining new command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63095/problem-with-alltt-package-when-defining-new-command)

It is (in simplified form):

```
\newenvironment{comm}[1]
{%
    #1%
    \begin{alltt}}
{\end{alltt}}
```

it works, but I need to put extra newline after `\begin`:

```
\begin{comm}

    user:        some-user
    password:    some-password
\end{comm}
```

Without this newline it looks like this:

[image]

This extra newline is not 'eaten' though, it is preserved, so you always have a huge vertial space before actual text. I tried to switch it for for example `\null` but it didn't work.

I tried to remove `%` signs and it worked exactly the same way.

This is not a big problem (I hacked it with some `vspace`), but I would like to know why is it so, because I think it might clarify some matters for me.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Why are you specifying an argument to the `comm` environment? Try removing `[1]` and `#1`.

Comment: Hi! Thanks, removing argument worked :) I used it because it was included in original example (in the question mention above). The fact that it shouldn't be there clears some things up. I think I got confused because I was trying many different options. If you make your comment an answer I can choose it as right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you're using tells LaTeX to look for an argument to the `comm` environment. Usually arguments are specified in braces, but the rules of TeX allow to specify it without braces: in this case it's the first token following.

So your attempt

```
\begin{comm}
  user:        some-user
  password:    some-password
\end{comm}
```

results in `u` to be the argument.

Since you don't need anything printed before the `alltt` environment, the solution is to say

```
\newenvironment{comm}
  {\begin{alltt}}
  {\end{alltt}}
```

By the way, it's a *good* idea to provide a proper name instead of using a generic environment, just as you're doing. You may later need to change how the environment must be printed; if you had used `alltt` everywhere, you'd need to look at each `alltt` environment in order to see if it is one that needs changes. By assigning a different name you can instead change the definition of `comm`, which would not affect other environments based on `alltt` you have in your document.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the additional clarification about the escaping `u`. In the last paragraph you mean using a more specific and self-explanatory name than `comm` or you mean something else? This command is just the basic one and I will add some other things to it.

Comment: @nuoritoveri The name should be useful to you for remembering what the environment is used for. What I meant is: if some particular logical unit appears frequently in a document, give it a name (with an environment or a command, depending on the object's nature). Thus your policy is correct!

Comment: Now I understand what you meant. I know it's important and I always try to do this, so thanks once more for help on this particular case.